# $route.routes prints URLs twice ,why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

i have created a basic app to learn angularJs routing.
When i printed `$routes.route` to the browser console , this is what i saw :

[image]

And this is my route configuration :

```
almRequirement.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller : 'homeController'
    }).when('/addRequirement', {
        templateUrl : 'addRequirement.html',
        controller : 'addRequirementController'
    }).when('/addModule', {
        templateUrl : 'addModule.html',
        controller : 'addModuleController'
    }).when('/addContraint', {
        templateUrl : 'addContraint.html',
        controller : 'addContraintController'
    }).when('/viewRequirement', {
        templateUrl : 'viewRequirement.html',
        controller : 'viewRequirementController'
    }).when('/updateRequirement/:reqId', {
        templateUrl : 'updateRequirement.html',
        controller : 'updateRequirementController'
    }).when('/viewParticularRequirement/:reqId', {
        templateUrl : 'viewParticularRequirement.html',
        controller : 'viewParticularRequirementController'
    });
});
```

Each URL configured in `$routeProvider.config()` is shown twice.Can anyone explain me why is it so ?

May be this would help me debug my application next time.

Comment: Could this be printing from each injected controller? Unlikely, I might add.

Comment: It appears that each parameter is unique. Some of them are differentiated only by a trailing slash, however.

Comment: could you show is your route definition and where you printed the routes

Comment: @TW80000 yes , i have also noticed that but that didn't help me much.

Comment: I don't understand what you think the problem is then. Each route is unique, and I'm assuming this is by design so someone who goes to `/addConstraint` for example wouldn't get an error for forgetting the trailing slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design in Angular. `$routeProvider.when()` adds a "redirect" to the user-specified path so with or without a trailing slash goes to the same place.

As [the source code states](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L68):

> @param {string} path Route path (matched against
>   `$location.path`). If `$location.path` contains redundant
>   trailing slash or is missing one, the route will still match and the
>   `$location.path` will be updated to add or drop the trailing slash to exactly match the route definition.

And here is the [source code for `when()`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L199) demonstrating that (my `/**** comments ****/` added):

```
this.when = function(path, route) {
    //copy original route object to preserve params inherited from proto chain
    var routeCopy = shallowCopy(route);
    if (angular.isUndefined(routeCopy.reloadOnSearch)) {
      routeCopy.reloadOnSearch = true;
    }
    if (angular.isUndefined(routeCopy.caseInsensitiveMatch)) {
      routeCopy.caseInsensitiveMatch = this.caseInsensitiveMatch;
    }

    /**** Add route as user specified it ****/

    routes[path] = angular.extend(
      routeCopy,
      path && pathRegExp(path, routeCopy)
    );

    // create redirection for trailing slashes
    if (path) {
      var redirectPath = (path[path.length - 1] === '/')
            ? path.substr(0, path.length - 1)
            : path + '/';

      /**** Add route with / added or stripped ****/

      routes[redirectPath] = angular.extend(
        {redirectTo: path},
        pathRegExp(redirectPath, routeCopy)
      );
    }

    return this;
  };
```

Comment: what do you mean by "`$routeProvider.when()` adds a redirect...." ? All user specified paths are redirects ,right ?